Left-normed commutators and normal subgroups
Notation and definitions
Let $G$ be a group. For $x_i \in G$, define the left-normed commutator $[x_1, ..., x_n]$ as  $[x_1]=x_1$, $[x_1, x_2]=x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}x_1x_2$, and $[x_1, ..., x_{i+1}]=[[x_1, ... x_i],x_{i+1}]$. We also define for subgroups $H_i \leq G$ their left-normed commutant $[H_1, ... H_n]$ as $[H_1]=H_1$, $[H_1, H_2]=\langle [h_1, h_2], h_j\in H_j\rangle$, and $[H_1, ..., H_{i+1}]=[[H_1, ..., H_i],H_{i+1}]$.
My question
Suppose $A, B, C \unlhd G$. Do we have $[A, B, C]=[B, C, A]=[C,A,B]$? In general, if $H_1, ... H_n \unlhd G$, $\sigma\in S_n$, is it true that $[H_1, ..., H_n]=[H_{\sigma(1)}, ..., H_{\sigma(n)}]$?
My attempt
The claim is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$ (it is a fact that $[A, B]=[B, A]$, since $[a,b]^{-1}=[b, a]$). If we may also show the above claim is true for $n=3$ (unsure about this - I suspect normality is used here), the more general claim follows by induction: Suppose the claim is true for $n\geq3$. If $\sigma(n+1)=n+1$, then we are done. Otherwise, if $\sigma(i)=n+1$ for $i<n+1$, we can repeatedly apply the $n=3$ case to "move" $H_{\sigma(i)}$ all the way to the right in $[H_{\sigma(1)}, ..., H_{\sigma(n+1)}]$. Then, apply the induction hypothesis on the new left-most $n$ terms.

Next to Arturo’s answer, you should also study the Three Subgroup Lemma. See Wikipedia.

No, this is not true in general.
Take $G=S_3$, $A=A_3$, $B=C=S_3$. Note that $[S_3,S_3]=A_3$, and $[A_3,S_3]=A_3$, as it is certainly  contained in $A_3$, and is nontrivial, since $A_3$ is not central; or explicitly, $[(123),(23)]=(132)(23)(123)(23)=(123)$.
So $[A,B,C]=[[A_3,S_3],S_3] = [A_3,S_3] = A_3$, but $[B,C,A]=[[S_3,S_3],A_3]=[A_3,A_3] =\{e\}$.
